# How do you say "hang out" in Esperanto?

Tags: word-usage, single-word-requests

In English, the phrase *hang out* means something like *to spend time doing nothing in particular*.

If I search for example sentences on tatoeba.org for the phrase "hang out" as in *Let's hang out this weekend*, the word *vagadi* is used, as in *Ni vagadu* for *Let's hang out*.

When I later looked up the word *vagi* at vortaro.net, it gives this definition:

> **vagadi** Daŭrevagi
>
> **vag/i** (ntr) Iri de unu loko en alian sen difinita celo

Or, an English translation from Lernu.net:

> **vagadi** (vag·ad·i ← vag·i) to wander around

So, the only place I see it meaning *hang out* is on a site where you have to be careful about who is translating the example sentences.

Is the word ***vagadi*** indeed recognized as slang for *to hang out*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I like to use the word *umi*. It has a nice slang feel to it whilst still being formed from an Esperanto root. PIV has the following definition:

> **umi** (fm) Fari ion ne precizigitan: *kion vi umas?; ni drinkas, fumas, inkas k umas, laŭ nia kaprico; la kantisto […] umas en la roksubgrunda medio en Britio; unu afiŝo en la kongresejo tekstis: «umu bone»; ŝi […] umis kun pluraj.*

I think the examples match the meaning of “hang out”.

So to translate “let’s hang out this weekend” you could say:

> Ni umu kune ĉi-semajnfine

*Vagadi* doesn’t seem like a good translation to me because it implies moving around. That would exclude just sitting in a bar or watching a film or which would be a common activity while “hanging out”.

Comment: I agree with the slang part, and I've seen young esperantists use "umi" in that way. According to PMEG though "umi " means "fari ion nedifineblan, strangan, hontindan...". It might cause some misunderstanding between generations, haha.

Answer (score 8):

I definitely also employ *-um-* for this. Instead of using it on its own (which I often do, but it obviously creates a highly context-dependent word), I usually tack it on to another root or affix that slightly disambiguates it.

Some examples used by me with my friends, though not necessarily universal or correct:

- amikumi - Wiktionary defines this as *to pass time with friends enjoying your amicable relations.* It's meaning isn;t identical to English's "hang out" but it's close in several senses.
- ĉeestumi - Personal word used by me to my friends, which I intend to mean "to be around, to be present, to *umi* while in attendance of something or in the presence of someone". I might use this not only to refer to the same idea as amikumi, but also to the idea of someone "hanging around" somewhere, like in English one might say "That guy has been hanging out in front of my house all day, I wonder what he wants." or "My mother is always (hanging) around."
- kunumi or kunestumi - another used by me, simply intending to mean something like "to do things while together; to be together". (*kunesti* is the common choice for "to be together"; I feel -umi- adds the nuance of "doing stuff" while being together.)

More specific words, same disclaimer as above:

- kafumi/teumi/trinkumi - When you're hanging out while consuming coffee/tea or some other non-alcoholic drink.
- drinkumi - Drinking alcohol while hanging out.
- kafejumi/drinkejumi, etc. - To hang out in a coffee shop, bar, etc.
- videoludumi - Hanging out while playing video games.

Following this pattern, it's clear that -um- is a highly versatile and ambiguous word and you can usually surround it with context to create a word that is somewhat difficult to translate out of Esperanto, but will make sense to whomever you're talking with at the time.